# Define float precision while taking input in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, precision

I want to define the precision of a float while taking it as an input

```
NGAS=float(input("enter a number with 3 decimal places"))
```

instead of mentioning the 3 decimal places I want to do the equivalent of

```
print('%.3f%' % ESTART)
```

while taking the input. Since, it affects my calculations.

Comment: Changing the `print` representation of a `float` won't impact your calculations. `float` is `float`, you don't get "3 decimal place floats". If you need to do decimal maths, you may need to use `decimal` module. This may be an XY problem.

Comment: @jpp What is an XY problem?

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/383944)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can round the inputted number:

```
ngas = round(float(input("enter a number: ")), 3)
```

Comment: While this answers OP's question, it doesn't address the potentially error-prone `Since, it affects my calculations` part. Your rounded `float` is still a `float`.